# Multivariate linear regression with 2 independent variables - formulae

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

I have regressed y on x1 and x2 in python but I get very different results when I do it by hand. I am using the following formulae:

http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Reg2IV.html

I am having hard time finding the formulae for a, b1 and b2 in the 2-variate regression:

$$ y = a + b_1x + b_2x $$

It is a bit silly to ask for this but everyone seems to be doing this with a software package and I want to do it by hand. Any useful references would be very appreciated.

Comment: Of course you will get different results depending on which regression technique you use.  The mathematically simplest is "least squares" but there are many more depending on which parameters one adopts to get "best fit".  That is, the regression technique will vary depending on the definition of "best fit".  What technique does Python use?  I am sure that others are available.

Comment: Are you familiar with basic matrix Algebra?

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan OLS, which is the default in statsmodels in python.

Comment: @V.Vancak Yes, I am.

Comment: @s5s - what is "OLS"?

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan Ordinary least squares. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OLS estimator of $b$ is given by 
$$
\hat{b} = \mathbf{(X ^ T X)^{-1}X ^ T  y },
$$
where $\mathbf{X}$ is $ n\times 3$ matrix, where the first column is all ones for the intercept and the other two consist of your $x_{1}$ and $x_2$ values respectively. Same structure holds for any number of variables $p$ with $\mathbf{X}_{n \times p}$.

Comment: OK, I don't think this can be done by hand :D, that is, $$(X^TX)^(-1) $$ will be hard to compute by hand?

Comment: @s5s OK, then this is thinly disguised least squares method - the proof is rather trivial and available in any text on the subject.  Actually, a 3x3 matrix is not all that difficult to invert by hand.

Comment: @s5s There are methods of getting around the explicit calculations: (1) Center the data and get rid of the intercept. (2) Invert "by hand" $3\times 3$ matrix. Not fun, but not so hard. (3) Verify the linked expression by inverting for the general case and then plug-in the sums. (4) Just solve $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_{1i}- \beta_2x_{2i})^2$ and derive the linked expression by yourself using only calculus.

Comment: Thanks - its been 6 years since I got my engineering degree and I haven't done any maths since then. I'd forgotten about this formulae. All worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have $n$ datapoints $(x_{1i},x_{2i},y_i)$ and you want to fit the model $$y = a + b_1\,x_1 + b_2\,x_2$$ for sure matrix calculation is simple.

Otherwise, build the standard normal equations for ordinary least-square methods; they are
$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i= n a + b_1\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i}+b_2\sum_{i=1}^n x_{2i}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i}\,y_i=  a\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i} + b_1\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_{1i}+b_2\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i}\,x_{2i}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{2i}\,y_i=  a\sum_{i=1}^n x_{2i} + b_1\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i}\,x_{2i}+b_2\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_{2i}$$ Three linear equations for the three unknown variables $a,b_1,b_2$.

Answer (score 0):

In the referenced page, the formulas of the slope and intercept for one variable function is given as:

> $$b=\frac{\sum xy}{\sum x^2}; \ \ \ \ \ \ a=\bar{y}-b\bar{x}.$$

whereas it must be:
$$b=\frac{SS_{xy}}{SS_{xx}}=\frac{\sum xy-\frac{\sum x\sum y}{n}}{\sum x^2-\frac{(\sum x)^2}{n}}; \ \ \ \ \ \ a=\bar{y}-b\bar{x}.$$

Note how it is similar with the matrix formula:
$$b=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY=\frac{X^TY}{X^TX}.$$

Once you understand the method of minimizing (setting partial derivatives to zero) the two variable function:
$$R^2(a,b)=\sum (y-a-bx)^2,$$
it is easy to generalize it to the three variable function:
$$R^2(a,b,c)=\sum (y-a-bx-cx^2)^2.$$